# How to use validation monitor in Softmax classifier in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, softmax

I just edit the [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py](http://mnist_softmax_classifier)   to enable logging by using a validation monitor

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
    from __future__ import division
    from __future__ import print_function

    # Import data
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

    import tensorflow as tf

    flags = tf.app.flags
    FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
    flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir', '/tmp/data/', 'Directory for storing data')

    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    # Create the model
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

    validation_metrics = {"accuracy": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy,
                          "precision": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision,
                          "recall": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall}
    validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
        mnist.test.images,
        mnist.test.labels,
        every_n_steps=50, metrics=validation_metrics,
        early_stopping_metric="loss",
        early_stopping_metric_minimize=True,
        early_stopping_rounds=200)
    # Define loss and optimizer
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

    # Train
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    for i in range(1000):
      batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
      train_step.run({x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

    # Test trained model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

But i am confused how i set  **validation_monitor** in this program. I have learned in  **DNNClassfier** , the validation_monitor is used in the flowwing way

```
# Fit model.
classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
               y=training_set.target,
               steps=2000, monitors=[validation_monitor])
```

So, how i can use validation_monitor in softmax_classifer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to do that, since `ValidationMonitor` is a part of `tf.contrib`, e.g. contribution code that is not supported by the TensorFlow team. So unless you are using some higher-level API from `tf.contrib` (like `DNNClassfier`), you might not be able to simply pass a `ValidationMonitor` instance to a optimizer's `minimize` method.

I believe your options are:

- Check how `DNNClassfier`'s `fit` method is implemented and utilise the same approach by manually handling a `ValidationMonitor` instance in your graph and session.
- Implement your own validation routine for logging and/or early stopping or whatever it is you intend to use `ValidationMonitor` for.